# Can I perform Wudu instead of ghusul if I have no hot water only cold?

Tags: wudu

Hi I have a question I was janaba (state of major ritual impurity) and had no running hot water only cold so I washed my self as best I could and performed Wudu instead and changed clothes and the closest place I could shower was my aunts 2.5 miles away is this acceptable?

Comment: We do not give personal verdicts. If you did not have hot water there were several was for you to acquire it. e.g. you could have used a pot to heat water on a stove and bathed using a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum and Praise be to Allah,
Lack of warm water or if there’s only cold water available is not a valid excuse to not perform wudu or ghusl if you need to. A valid excuse of not performing ghusl or wudu would be if there literally is no water around at all or if the water is not safe to use or isn’t clean water

Comment: Assalamualeykum yes however cold water is unsafe especially since we were in the winter and therefore performing full ghusul without harming my self was near impossible therefore I made Wudu